# xpath searching with php

Tags: php, xml, search, xpath

I am attempting to search an XML document using XPATH with a value from a form but i am met with a number of errors.

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: Invalid
>   expression on line 17
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath()
>   [simplexmlelement.xpath]: xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed on line 17
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 21

holidays.xml snippet

```
<channel>
    <item>
          <title>Holiday description</title> 
          <link>link</link> 
          <description>Holiday description</description> 
          <pubDate>Sun, 13 Feb 2011 11:58:17 GMT</pubDate> 
          <guid>http://site</guid> 
      </item>
</channel
```

txtSearch is the text value taken from the form. Can anyone shed any light on fixing these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
$qry = "channel/item/[contains(text()),'$txtSearch']";
```

to this

```
$qry = sprintf('channel/item[contains(., "%s")]', $txtSearch);
```

and then it should work.

Note that when you use `'channel'`, the query is relative to the `SimpleXMLElement` you called the xpath method on. Use `'/channel'` when you want to start from the root node. And use `'//channel'` when you want to search everywhere in the document.

Also have a look at this [XPath tutorial](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have error in this line `$qry = "channel/item/[contains(text()),'$txtSearch']";`
Wrong bracket closing. also you should specify in what node you want search, for `description` node you can use following xpath:
`$qry = "//channel/item[description[contains(text(),\"$txtSearch\")]]";`

update:
sure, Gordon's variant is better: `$qry = "//channel/item[contains(.,\"$txtSearch\")]";`